# Use encrypted home or a ATA password on a Intel 330 SSD?

Tags: encryption, ssd

I plan to buy a Intel 330 SSD (encrypts all data whit AES 128) and use it in a Asus EeePC 1215N (supports ATA password) whit the latest *ubuntu and Windows 7. I'm a fair paranoid user and security mathers but I also want a good performance and no trouble. The important data will be in ~ and is not needet to be accessible from Windows. But to have everything encrypted would be welcome.

Is it better to use a encrypted home or simply set a ATA password (the data on the SSD is encrypted by the device regardless)? Which is more secure and easier to handle?

I'm specially worried about suspend to RAM / drive (is it working and still secure?). I know suspend to drive is not possible whit a encrypted swap (I need a swap). And I read about hot swap attacks to Selfencrypted devices (but on this Laptop the SSD is under the keyboard and hard to reach).
Whit a encrypted home and swap, how much would be the performance loss (as this device gains speed through compressing the data)?
Is it possible to uses the ATA password to login the usere?

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at my other [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201744/swap-encryption-and-hibernating) about full disk encryption. It doesn't cover your Windows partition, though. You can of course dedicate one partition for Windows by slightly altering my instructions but it won't be encrypted.

I think I wouldn't rely on a vendor provided encryption method for anything that I care about but that's just my opinion.