# Why is the default boot partition so small with whole disk encryption option?

Tags: boot, partitioning

The boot partition, set up automatically by the Ubuntu installer, is only ~230MB.  This is the case on two different clean installs I have performed on different machines.  Both used the full disk encryption option.  One is desktop Ubuntu, the other used the server ISO.  I tell the installer to partition automatically, using the whole (only) disk.

230MB can only fit about five kernels, so after a few automatic updates /boot warnings begin to appear.  The only solution is to clean them out manually (not well documented).

Is there a reason the boot partition is so small?  Why are there no mechanisms to clean out old kernels automatically?  Is this a bug I should report?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/184358/30266

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but I find this inconvenient as well. <strike>Fortunately, current Ubuntu 14.10 supports setting up full disk encryption with manual specification of the partitioning. I don't know about older versions.</strike>

Working around this issue is a bit tedious:

1. Use a text mode installer (I used a ["Server" image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)) or a live CD to configure partitioning.

   - Create a reasonably sized primary boot partition and one extended partition to hold all LVM partitions (at minimum, root and swap). Detailed instructions in [this wonderful answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/201868/30266).
   - It's safe to shut down the system after the partitioning has finished
2. When installing your favorite flavor of Ubuntu, mount encrypted file systems before installing:  (See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsViaUbiquity) for an official statement and a guide for the command line (a substitute for my instructions below), and [this Launchpad issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1066480) for some context).

   - Choose "Try Ubuntu" after booting live disk.
   - Mount the encrypted partitions (e.g., in Nautilus)
       [image: Nautilus]
   - Backup **at least** `/etc` from the mounted encrypted partition

     - You can simply move everything to a new folder `/z` with `cd *; mkdir z; mv * z` in a root shell

       - ignore the warning that `mv` prints
   - Eject the encrypted partition in Nautilus
   - Start installation using the desktop icon
   - Do not unmount anything when asked
     [image: Don't unmount]
   - Choose a custom install
     [image: Custom install]
   - Specify partitions that will contain `/` and `/boot`
     [image: Mount points]
   - **IMPORTANT**: After installation, **do not reboot**
   - Mount the encrypted root again in Nautilus
   - Restore `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` from your backup (in `/z` if you followed the suggestion)
   - Recreate the contents of `/boot`. In a root shell:

     ```
     cd /media/*/* # location of mounted encrypted root
     chroot .
     mount dev
     mount proc
     mount run
     mount sys
     mount boot
     update-initramfs -u -k all
     update-grub
     umount boot
     umount sys
     umount run
     umount proc
     umount dev
     exit
     ```
   - Reboot

Instead of step 2, you can also finish a "minimal" install (choose it with F4 on the first screen; details in [this other wonderful answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/207241/30266)) and manually pull in your desktop packages into your "Server" system.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup cron.monthly to run

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-44 linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-48 linux-headers-3.13.0-48-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-49 linux-headers-3.13.0-49-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-51 linux-headers-3.13.0-51-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-52 linux-headers-3.13.0-52-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 20 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

This is very useful if you are autodownloading the kernels about ever 3 weeks, because apt will start to fail.

Do not manually delete the old kernels as the grub config will get messed up.

grub2 reconfig is run automatically when the kernels are removed by this processes.

`[..snip..]
done
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic (3.13.0-51.84) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-54-generic
[..snip..]`

Comment: if your wondering its the `update-grub` command that fixes the grub identification of kernels