# Resizing crypt partionon Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: encryption

How to resize and format cryp-luks encrypted partition to ntfs(Ubuntu 15.04)?

Need detailed step by step explanation please!!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? resizing an encrypted Luks partition is difficult and dangerous. Reformating the entire partition to ntfs is something entirely different and would require you to backup and restore all data. Also NTFS doesn't support linux file permissions so you can't install Ubuntu on it.

Comment: Linux while installing doesn't configure the file system?     I want the other partition for trying other operating systems

Comment: Yes, the Ubuntu installer will give you an option to choose a file system, however NTFS is not supported, as it doesn't support linux file permissions. By 'other partition' I assume you mean 'different formatting'. But I would suggest you just backup your data elsewhere and install whatever 'other operating systems' you like.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/184358/resizing-boot-partition-with-full-disk-encryption/868768#868768